# What is the object type that handles true application Menu Bars?

Tags: swift, menu

I don't want to use Obj C I want to use native Swift menu's in the standard menu bar.  Like these:

[image: Safari Menu]

The code examples that I find keep doing standard toolbar menu's.  I'm not writing an iOS application, I'm writing a standard Mac application.  I'm trying to keep things very simple.  I've tried putting in a .menu which is what somebody suggested and also tried: Menu("Actions") { Button("do X", ... ), but .menu is not allowed in a Scene and Menu() does not 'conform'.

On a related note I have created my toolbars already and I'm trying to set-up a design pattern where I can put any menu anywhere.  So font menus (font, size etc) can be in a context menu or in a standard application menu.  Basically designing the UI first then adding functionality.  I'll be writing two applications at the same time and I'm trying to get consistency between them.

Comment: MenuBarExtra or Commands should be your search words

Comment: @loremipsum MenuBarExtra seams to used for those 'special' menu's on the right side of the menu bar.  Search, Date, Time preferences etc.

Comment: I also mentioned commands

Comment: TY!! Had to go to Costco to shop with the wife.  I'm about to fool around with both of these and see what they can do.  It's really to bad Apple designed this all wrong.  There should be one menu, menuBar, and menuBarItem.  No need for button if you define an action it becomes a button.  There are so many combinations.  All you need to do is define where target is.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do. You're writing an app in Swift and you want to add menus and menu commands?

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, it's that simple.  I expected something like MenuBar, Menu and MenuItem but evidently in Apples wisdom they named it something else.  There should be ONLY one type of menu and a property such as target or location to specify the position (NavigationBar, sidebar etc).  I'm trying to keep this alive since clearly there are dozens of videos out there and nobody talks about the actual application menu bar.  Everybody talks about a toolbar or sidebar menu.

Comment: Actually providing a class or function names would be a FACT.  I'm clearly NOT asking for a book recommendation.

Comment: TY @loremipsum  .commands was the answer.  I don't know how to give you credit though.  Maybe people can keep up voting your answer above now that this is still an open issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu in your picture is the commands menu.

It is accessed via

```
.commands(content:)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scene/commands(content:)

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10041

```
@main
struct BookClubApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            List {
                Text("Reading List Viewer")
            }
        }
        .commands {
            Button("Previous Book", action: selectPrevious)
                .keyboardShortcut("[")
            Button("Next Book", action: selectNext)
                .keyboardShortcut("]")
        }
    }

    private func selectPreviousBook() {}
    private func selectNextBook() {}
}
```

Comment: Hopefully people can find this answer TY again.

Comment: @Keith terminology is tough with these menus, if you don’t know it you just don’t know.